# We roll a cube until the first time that the sum of rolls is even. Find probability that we will roll the cube more than twice

Tags: probability

We have a cube with 6 sides numbered 1 through 6. We roll the cube repeatedly until the first time that the sum of all of our rolls is even, at which time we stop. (Note: it is possible to roll the cube just once.) What is the probability that we will need to roll the cube more than 2 times in order to get an even sum?

**My solution:** If we need to roll more than twice, it means that we will have an odd number on the first roll and an even on the second roll.

P(Odd on the first trial) = $\dfrac{1}{2}$

P(Even on second trial given odd on first trial) = P(Even on second **AND** Odd on first) / P(odd on first)

P(Even on second **AND** Odd on first) = P(Even on second trial given odd on first trial) $\times$  P(odd on first)

Since, the two events are independent, P(Even on second trial given odd on first trial) = 1/2

P(Even on second **AND** Odd on first) = $\dfrac{1}{2} \times \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{1}{4}$

A different solution is available in the book and I can understand it, but I want to know whether my approach is correct not?

Comment: As you noted, the outcomes of the different rolls are independent. So the probability is indeed the probability of odd on the first roll, times probability of even on the second roll: $\frac12 * \frac12 = \frac14$

Comment: @Alborz, thank you so much :)

Comment: Though your steps are correct, it is a little redundant to use these conditional probabilities when you have already identified that the outcomes from different rolls are independent. Not wrong though.